# How to prevent link search from spilling across tags?

Tags: html, regex, url

How to prevent link search from spilling across tags?

I have a local web site whose pages contain hyperlinks of various classes and would like to know how to prevent search results from spilling across several tags. (I need to do a batch modification of the address of a particular link type.)

E.g., my page may contain lists of links such as

```
Best solution:<br>
<a href="aaa.html" class="xxx">AAA</a><br> but see also
<a href="bbb.html" class="yyy">BBB</a><br> and
<a href="ccc.html" class="zzz">CCC</a><br>.
```

Now when I try to search the site for only the links of class "zzz" using the regex search term

```
<a href="+[].html" class="zzz">
```

my results include long strings such as

`<a href="aaa.html" class="xxx">AAA</a><br> but see also <a href="bbb.html" class="yyy">BBB</a><br> and <a href="ccc.html" class="zzz>`

What has happened is that the search engine (Funduc Search & Replace, if this helps) finds the `<a href=` of the first link (aaa.html), the matching class of the third link (ccc.html), and includes everything in between.

What expression must I use to ensure only the link of the file with the correct class, and nothing else, appears in the search result?

E.g.,

```
<a href="ccc.html" class="zzz>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wish I knew. I've searched Funduc's site, the Help guide and the web without discovering what type it is. It doesn't appear to be exactly standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DOM library (preferably one that supports XPath) instead of a regular expression. Regular expressions are poorly suited to dealing with HTML.

Comment: Data extraction is OK, though. Extensive manipulation will need parser.

Comment: Had no luck so far using Funduc. What do ppl recommend as best for such "wildcard" manipulation of HTML?

Comment: I tend towards [Perl](http://www.perl.org/get.html) and [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

Comment: But OP tagged the question with regex. However, DOM rewrite will usually break the code level consistency, introduced in lots of unrelated diff lines to commit.

Comment: There is also [html2/2html](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) utilities from Dan Egnor, to convert html to/from text lines. It's useful if the html is ugly formatted, and you still want to use line by line text processors. It's very easy and fast, like `html2 < in.html | sed -e ... | 2html > out.html`. However, I didn't see a Win32 port..

Answer (score 0):

The `+` modifier for one or more occurrences, is eager to match in most regex engine. That means, `[a-z]+` means "Match a or b or ... or z as many as possible".

Perl regex engine has a special modifier `+?` for lazy match, so `[a-z]+?` means "Match a..z as few as possible".

Simply, you can exclude `"`, `>` from "any char" to match:

```
[^">]+
```

The regex will be look like:

```
<a href="([^">]+.html)" class="zzz">
```

A more precised perl version:

```
<a\s+.*?\bhref\s*=\s*"(.+?\.html)"\s*class\s*=\s*"zzz".*?>
```

Here `()` for capture group.

I haven't tried with `Funduc Search and Replace for Windows`, hope it works.

Comment: I don't think Perl works well here. Some improvement using your first suggestion, none with second. In Funduc S&R, search and replace terms use different operators. Thanks anyway for responding.

Comment: um.. "none with second", do you mean the third? Well, I give the perl version doesn't mean you need to work with Perl, but instead some utilities support Perl style regex. (UltraEdit for example).